# In x8086 Assembly Language, how do I read string from the console and store it into a variable?

Tags: string, assembly, masm, x86-16

I am currently working on a project that requires the user to enter a password and then have that password checked under certain conditions. I am having trouble getting started with declaring a string variable and then populating that variable with char inputs. Here's my code that does this so far:

```
input    DB   20  DUP(?)

pass_input: 
mov ah, 08h ; no echo
int 21h
mov dx, OFFSET ast ; ast = * to keep password hidden
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
loop pass_input
```

Comment: You need a pointer to the `input` then write the character there and increment.

Comment: Assembly language doesn't have "strings", "variables" or "declaring".  You have memory and you store bytes in it.

Comment: can I do this?  'code' mov input[si], al and then increment the source index

Comment: Check out DOS `int 21h` function `0Ah`.

Comment: Yes `mov input[si]` should work. @WeatherVane that's not very useful for password entry ;)